# Using environment variables from ~/.bashrc in "npm start"?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I tried to find a similar question but couldn't. Here's the breakdown:

I need to use a secret key with a package I'm building and I don't want to publish it so I'm trying to set it as a local bash environment variable. In my .bashrc file I have this:

```
# Obviously this is not the REAL key, just an example
MY_KEY="1111111111111111"
```

And then in my Gulpfile, I have a task called "dev". For simplicity sake, let's say it looks like this:

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
  console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
});
```

Then, in order to get the secret key into the environment, I have the following in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "SECRET_KEY=$MY_KEY gulp dev"
}
```

So the problem is, when I run the command `npm start`, my gulp task logs `undefined` for the secret key. But when I manually run the command `SECRET_KEY=$MY_KEY gulp dev`, the gulp task logs `1111111111111111`. So, for some reason, `npm start` is not correctly accessing my bash variable and passing it into the Node environment. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: BTW, see POSIX conventions for environment variable naming at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- all-uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the system or shell; lowercase names are guaranteed (from the perspective of POSIX-specified OS components) to be safe for applications to use. Granted, this is rather wildly ignored convention, but it avoids mistakes like making your own variable named `PATH` and wondering why your shell can no longer run external programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just creates a *shell variable*, not an environment variable:

```
MY_KEY="1111111111111111"
```

To export that shell variable into the environment:

```
export MY_KEY
```

Comment: Ah yes, that looks like it may solve the problem. Can I have more than 1 export command in my bashrc?

Comment: Of course, yes -- or you can put multiple variable names on a single `export`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Sorry for being a bash n00b.

Comment: ...btw, once it's exported into the environment, any updates will immediately be reflected in the environment, so you only need to `export` each variable once (and since `PATH` will pretty much always be in the environment before your scripts are started, anyone running `export PATH` is being unnecessarily verbose).